# Dynamcis AX 365 OData v4.0, method get Customers from AX 365 with key not found

Tags: odata, dynamics-ax7

I’m trying to reach a single entity according to instructions:

[Organization Root URL]/data/Customers('key')

but all I get is HTTP 404 Not Found.

When I try:

[Organization Root URL]/data/Customers

I get all customers just as expected. I am able to reach a single entity with:

[Organization Root URL]/data/Customers?$filter=CustomerAccount eq ‘key’

My main objective is to be able to invoke an action defined on the data entity. To be able to do that (as I understand it) you have to be able to reach a single entity including the action through:

[Organization Root URL]/data/Customers(‘key’)/ActionName

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

The key for a customer needs to be specified as follows

```
[Organization Root URL]/data/Customers(CustomerAccount='US_SI_0072',dataAreaId='USSI')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your purpose is not clear here.
You cannot directly call the action written on data entity.

data entity in AX supports CRUD operations with method types as
Create(C)- POST
Read(R) - GET
UPDATE(U) - Patch
Delete(D) - Delete

To only read the records, you can directly run the URL in browser. But for other operations, you need to have some client like POSTMAN or FIDDLER or if you are good enough with C# coding you can use Visual studio.

Except READ, all other operations require some kind of parameters and/or Request body along with authentication token.

On each of the operation, some methods/event gets called in AX where you can write your own custom logic. 
e.g., If you are executing patch method, it calls update method on data entity.

go through the below wiki help, you'll find everything about data entities in AX
https://ax.help.dynamics.com/en/wiki/data-entities-home-page/